# Why ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined, when I'm not using it at all?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, react-testing-library

I've created a tiny app with React and Nest, to understand WebScoket api.
Not to just waste time, I wanted to wrap it as a deployable app, and host it somewhere.

The code is here: https://github.com/An1mus/chitchat

While adding some basic workflows, I've faced an issue with the following error, that appears after running the tests (the test cases are passing):

```
/Users/andrewpetrov/Projects/an1mus/chitchat/client/node_modules/.pnpm/xmlhttprequest-ssl@2.0.0/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:628
        setImmediate(function() { self["on" + event]() })
        ^

ReferenceError: setImmediate is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (/Users/andrewpetrov/Projects/an1mus/chitchat/client/node_modules/.pnpm/xmlhttprequest-ssl@2.0.0/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:628:9)
    at setState (/Users/andrewpetrov/Projects/an1mus/chitchat/client/node_modules/.pnpm/xmlhttprequest-ssl@2.0.0/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:654:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (/Users/andrewpetrov/Projects/an1mus/chitchat/client/node_modules/.pnpm/xmlhttprequest-ssl@2.0.0/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:572:5)
    at ClientRequest.errorHandler (/Users/andrewpetrov/Projects/an1mus/chitchat/client/node_modules/.pnpm/xmlhttprequest-ssl@2.0.0/node_modules/xmlhttprequest-ssl/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:490:14)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:454:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

For some reason it fires, when I run tests, even though my only test is this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('renders the app', async () => {
  // this is a workaround for issue #1695 in jsdom
  window.HTMLElement.prototype.scrollIntoView = function() {};

  const {container} = await render(<App />);
  expect(container.querySelector('h1')).toHaveTextContent('Welcome to ChitChat')
});
```

The test runs with `react-scripts test --watchAll=false`

What can cause an error like that?
My guess was that I wrote the test incorrectly, of it is somehow related to WebScokets being rendered along side the App.

I'll be grateful for any hint.

Comment: experiencing the same issue with https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-workshop-js repo which uses the same stuff under the hood

Answer (score 3):

Probably a little late to answer this but this seems to be an issue with the node environment.

To fix this :

1. Install polyfill: npm install --save setimmediate
2. In your setupTests.js: import 'setimmediate';

Comment: It is never too late. The fact of not having an answer was bothering :)
Thank you, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

After research about this issue.

I found 2 main threads that can help you.

1. You can take a look at this https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/8558
   What I can found that is relevant for you, add this into the `jest.config.js`:

```
global.setImmediate = jest.useRealTimers;
```

There is a similar approach on the same thread:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */

import {setImmediate} from 'timers'
```

2. The other approach that I found was that `jsdom` was deprecated and now the set up on the `jest.config.js` file should be:

```
testEnvironment: 'node'
```

This is deprecated since v27. You can expand the information here:
https://jestjs.io/blog/2021/05/25/jest-27